# Change XFA field font size without breaking usage rights

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xfa

I am trying to fill data in a XFA document and also change the font size of the data filled in the text box. I have managed to fill data in the XFA doc using `PdfStamper` in Append mode and using the `FillXfaForm` method on the `XfaForm` object. This approach correctly fills the XFA doc while preserving the usage rights.
But now I also want to change the font size of the filled data. This font size property is in the `Template` of the XFA doc. From my understanding I cant use the `FillXfaForm` method to change things in `Template` of XFA. Therefore, I am using the `SetXfa` method on `XfaForm` object to change the font size and field value. 
Code:

```
public void Fill()
{
    string nodeName = "form1[0].Page1[0].xxxxxx[0].yyyyy[0].zzzzzzz[0]";

    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
    using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(destinationFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream, '\0', true))
        {
            var form = stamper.AcroFields;
            var xfaForm = form.Xfa;

            // set field value
            xfaForm.DatasetsSom.Name2Node[nodeName].InnerText = "54321";

            // get the <font /> node
            var fontNode = xfaForm
                .TemplateSom
                .Name2Node[nodeName]
                .ChildNodes
                .Cast<XmlNode>()
                .First(n => n.Name.Equals("font"));

            // set font size
            fontNode.Attributes["size"].Value = "12pt";

            xfaForm.Changed = true;
            xfaForm.SetXfa(stamper.Writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly fills the XFA doc and sets the font size but, it violates the usage rights and I get this message when I open the filled XFA doc in adobe reader:

> This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader. The document has been
>   changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available. Please
>   contact the author for the original version of this document.

If I remove the changing font size part and keep using the `SetXfa` to fill data then I dont get the above error message.

I have read the Chapter 8 of "iText in Action" book but couldn't figure out how to change font size while preserving usage rights.

I am using iTextSharp. I am willing to upgrade to iText7 if iText7 can fix this problem.

Comment: Usage rights allow only some changes, not others. Usually changes like fill-ins are allowed while changes of the form setup are not. So I assume your change simply cannot be executed without breaking the usage rights.